# Google analytics measurement protocol timeout

Tags: curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, php-curl

I'm trying to send hit to google analytics measurement protocol and get timeout exception. Hits send by curl library, i tried to increase timeout but it didn't help. This issue appears randomly

```
  * Connection #7 to host www.google-analytics.com left intact    
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-61364284-1&geoid=1011969&cm=cpc&cs=smi&cn=1322_5&ul=ru-ru&t=pageview&v=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fnominaltechno.ru&cid=a4788d46-3628-4132-a5d9-505201581b59&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28X11%3B%20Linux%20i586%3B%20rv%3A31.0%29%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F31.0&sc=start&qt=5688590    
* Hostname was found in DNS cache    
*   Trying 172.217.20.206...    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable      
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
* connect to 172.217.20.206 port 443 failed: Connection timed out    
*   Trying 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e...    
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:401b:803::200e: Network is unreachable    
* Failed to connect to www.google-analytics.com port 443: Connection timed out    
* Closing connection 8
```

Can anybody explain what caused the problem? Thank for answers

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your request against the debug endpoint

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?tid=UA-61364284-1&geoid=1011969&cm=cpc&cs=smi&cn=1322_5&ul=ru-ru&t=pageview&v=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fnominaltechno.ru&cid=a4788d46-3628-4132-a5d9-505201581b59&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28X11%3B%20Linux%20i586%3B%20rv%3A31.0%29%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F31.0&sc=start&qt=5688590
```

Response:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?tid=UA-61364284-1\u0026geoid=1011969\u0026cm=cpc\u0026cs=smi\u0026cn=1322_5\u0026ul=ru-ru\u0026t=pageview\u0026v=1\u0026dl=http%3A%2F%2Fnominaltechno.ru\u0026cid=a4788d46-3628-4132-a5d9-505201581b59\u0026ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20i586%3B%20rv%3A31.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F31.0\u0026sc=start\u0026qt=5688590"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Which tells us its a valid hit.  Then I put it in a web browser (chrome) which returned the proper gif.  You may have just seen a hit coming from Denmark that was me.

I think there is something up with your curl setup.

> **Curl Error Hostname Not Found in DNS Cache**: curl failed to connect to that host's TCP port number 80.

Comment: Don't think it curl setup problem, because some of requests reaches destination, i also tried to send hits to debug endpoint and via console, it was ok


`$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);
curl_close($ch);`


I also tried to send request by Guzzle library but it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried placing your request in a simple browser? Its just a http get call.   I think you should include all of the code you are using in your question I would be happy to test it from my end. The call works its not analytics this is a Curl error.

Comment: yes, i tried to make request via simple browser, and it was ok, thanks for answer, i'll try to review curl setup

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm that the request going though both via curl and in the browser.

Comment: i noticed that curl trying to connect to 172.217.20.206, get timeout and then trying to connect to 172.217.20.174 and get proper response. Can it be connected with CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT ?